# Adding weights to some directed and undirected edges of this graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this graph:

[image: Digraph]

I would like to add nodes for specifying weights to some arrows and undirected edges. Edge (A)(r) should have capacity = `\infty`, and some undirected edges should have some numbers associated to their nodes.

I coded the edges by separating undirected arrows (using `(n1) edge (n2)` notation for undirected edges, and using `\draw [->]` for directed edges). The problem with this is that, for arrows, I can't change the code into something like `(n1) edge node[MyStyle]{T} (n2)`, and I can't write it in the undirected edge set, because this would draw two separate edges between the same nodes.

How could I tweak this code in a simple way, to obtain what I want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=1.2,auto=left, every node/.style={ circle, fill=blue!20,   minimum size=2.5mm, inner sep=2pt}
              ]

\tikzset{My Style/.style={scale=0.8, black,fill=white,opacity=.2,text opacity=1, minimum size=0.5cm, }}

\tikzset{>=latex}

\node  [fill = white, draw = black] (n1) at (0, 4){A};
\node  [rectangle] (n2) at (1, 4){r};
\node  [rectangle] (n3) at (2, 5){p};
\node  [rectangle] (n4) at (3.5, 5){q};
\node  [rectangle] (n5) at (3.5, 3.5){s};
\node  [fill = white, draw = black] (n6) at (5, 4){B};
    \path

(n2) edge[bend left = 15] (n3)
(n3) edge (n4)
(n4) edge (n5)
(n2) edge[bend right = 15] (n5);

\draw [->]   (n1) edge (n2) (n4) edge[bend left = 15]  (n6) (n5) edge[bend right = 15] (n6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addind nodes afterwards with coordinates is definitely **not** a good idea, because they won't follow any of the changes you would do on your original graph.
Instead, you would use the following structure: `\path (n1) edge node{content} (n2);` like in the code below.
Note that you didn't have to draw separately the edges without arrows and the ones with. Adding `[->]` after `edge` into your path is enough to chose which one should wear an arrow.

I also defined `scopes` to allow you using different kinds of `node styles` without having to write them everywhere. Now you should be able to customize the picture as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.5,auto=left]
    
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style=
                            {fill=blue!20,
                             minimum size=2.5mm,
                             inner sep=2pt}]
                \node  [circle,fill = white, draw = black] (n1) at (0, 4){A};
                \node  (n2) at (1, 4){r};
                \node  (n3) at (2, 5){p};
                \node  (n4) at (3.5, 5){q};
                \node  (n5) at (3.5, 3.5){s};
                \node  [circle,fill = white, draw = black] (n6) at (5, 4){B};
            \end{scope}
            
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={inner sep=1pt}]
                \path
                    (n1) edge[->] node {$\infty$} (n2)
                    (n2) edge[bend left = 15] node{$4$}  (n3) 
                    (n3) edge (n4)
                    (n4) edge (n5)
                    (n2) edge[bend right = 15] node {$-8$}(n5)
                    (n4) edge[->,bend left = 15]  (n6) 
                    (n5) edge[->,bend right = 15] (n6);
            \end{scope}      
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes on graph edges]

Comment: Note that you can customize your edge nodes globally (in the scope declaration) and also locally (behind each `node`), like this `(n2) edge[bend right = 15] node[below] {$-8$}(n5)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add new nodes:

```
\node [fill = white, scale= 0.6] (v1) at (0.5, 4.1){$\infty$};
\node [fill = white, scale= 0.6, rotate = -25] (v2) at (4.25, 4.84){$\infty$};
\node [fill = white, scale= 0.6] (v3) at (4.24, 3.72){$0$};
```